# Interplay maximum clique size and number of contained triangles in a graph with particular restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For a research interest, I'm wrestling with the following situation.

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the collection of connected graphs with $n$ vertices, $m=\binom{n-2}{2}+2$ edges, minimum vertex degree $d$ and independence number $2$. Suppose that $G=\arg\max_{G\in\mathcal{G}} T(G)$, where $T(G)$ denotes the number of triangles contained in $G$. I would like to conclude that $G$ also (not necessarily uniquely) maximizes the clique number over $\mathcal{G}$.

Would anyone be able to help me out with some intuition as to the correctness of the statement and potentially a (preferably short) line of proof? Thanks!